# I get cannot resolve package xxx

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I create a java application user IntelliJ IDEA, when I config the `Dept.hbm.xml`, I get the error:

> Cannot resolve package ypd ...

[image]

But you can see, the directory lib is:

```
src/main/java/com/ypd...
```

My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ypd.sp.entity">

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Why I got this error?

---

**EDIT**

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringAndHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```

---

**EDIT**

If in Project Structure, I make the package as Source Root, there is no way, why?

[image]

Comment: please dont use the images. Use the <code sample>.

Comment: @hanumant in this specific case the screenshot helps to understand the problem with the incorrect source root configuration, it would not be possible with just the code, so screenshots are not always bad

Comment: right click src > mark directory as > unmark as sources root THEN

right click java > mark directory as > sources root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you import the project from Maven? If so, please share `pom.xml`, it may override the default source folder location (`src/main/java`).

The problem is that you have the [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html#d2322883e194) configured incorrectly. According to the screenshot, `src` is configured as **Sources** instead of `src/main/java`.

Delete `.idea` directory and Open `pom.xml`, the roots will be configured automatically.

Comment: I see your <a src="http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html#d2322883e194">link</a>, but how can I set the source-root? I have post the pom.xml too.

Comment: Delete `.idea` directory and Open `pom.xml`, the roots will be configured automatically.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ is telling you what's wrong.

It says the package name is `java.com.ypd.sp.entity`.

Looks like you made `/main` the Java source directory.

You should mark `/java` as the Java source directory.  That should be blue.

Answer (score 0):

As duffymo said, you did not set the the source directory correctly, and your settings of Source is wrong, follow the below steps:

1) File -> Project Structure... (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> your system is in Mac)

[image]

2) Modules -> your project name -> Sources -> The root library you want to set(In general is src/main/java) -> Right Click -> Sources.

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to configure the source roots manually in a Maven based project, instead, opening `pom.xml` will configure the roots automatically in IntelliJ IDEA.